# Install Phppgadmin without apache

Tags: apt, postgresql, phppgadmin

I'm trying to setup a `nginx`+`postgresql` testing server,but when i try to install `phppgadmin` it tries to install `apache2`, I don't want to install `apache2`, is there a way to install it without apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the package shows (`apt-cache show phppgadmin`):

```
Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 | php5-cgi, php5-pgsql, apache2 | httpd, libjs-jquery
```

the package depends on `apache2` **or** `httpd`. It will favor `apache2`. So, just pass `nginx` explicitly and it should install, because `nginx` offers `httpd` (see output of `apt-cache showpkg httpd`).

```
$ apt-cache showpkg httpd|grep nginx
nginx-naxsi 1.4.6-1ubuntu3
nginx-light 1.4.6-1ubuntu3
nginx-full 1.4.6-1ubuntu3
nginx-extras 1.4.6-1ubuntu3
nginx-core 1.4.6-1ubuntu3
```

#### Edit:

Tried this myself on Ubuntu 14.04 just to find out that it doesn't work. Apparently one of the dependencies is hardcoded and not tied to `httpd` only. Presumably because no configuration exists for anything other than Apache? Anyway, I set out to find out and it turns out the `Depends` line from above holds the key. It's not just `apache2 | httpd` but also `libapache2-mod-php5 | php5-cgi`. So we need to be explicit about these things as well.

The package `apt-rdepends` shows what's going on:

```
$ apt-rdepends phppgadmin|grep apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
  Depends: apache2
  Depends: libapache2-mod-php5
apache2
  Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4)
  Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4)
apache2-bin
apache2-data
libapache2-mod-php5
  Depends: apache2 (>= 2.4)
  Depends: apache2-api-20120211
apache2-api-20120211
```

The `libapache2-mod-php5` line is also to be found in the dependencies of `phppgadmin` and is the issue here.

Therefore we end up with:

```
$ apt-get install --no-install-recommends nginx php5-cgi phppgadmin
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need apt to install phppgadmin.

Download the compressed folder [from sourceforge](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php?id=download) and unzip into your root (or into a folder that you symlink into your root).
That's all you need to be up and running. Some points that might help:

- PhpPgAdmin requires another user besides postgres. In Linux:
  `$ sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser --pwprompt dev`
- If you get `login failed`, you probably are connected over Unix socket.
  Edit pg_hba.conf (/etc/postgresql/9.x/main/pg_hba.conf).
  Replace `local all all peer` with `local all all md5`
- If you get a 403 error, then phppgadmin was probably unzipped as root.
  Change the user to www-data: `sudo chown -R www-data phppgadmin`
- The detailed install instructions can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin/master/INSTALL), and [common issues here](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php?id=faq).

Using --no-install-recommends as 0xC0000022L suggested does not work, as Apache is a dependency, not a recommendation.
He correctly explained the issue, though. If you use apt, the install will probably work, it just will install Apache and then err out when Apache is unable to run.

Comment: Using --no-install-recommends works on Ubuntu 14.04 - only php5-cgi, php5-pgsql and phppgadmin were installed in my case.

Comment: @SamGoody: you are wrong. The main point is **not** to use `--no-install-recommends` (and my answer does not imply that). The main point is that the dependency is `apache2 | httpd` and that `nginx` *provides* `httpd`. And equally that we can use either the favored `libapache2-mod-php5` which will *again* try to pull `apache2` in or explicitly ask for `php5-cgi` So by installing `nginx php5-cgi` explicitly we sidestep the installation of `apache2` which would otherwise be favored (unless another `httpd` "provider" is already installed). It really is as simple as that.